SwaggerUI with SpringDoc not converting multi value parameter
We recently migrated our application from Spring Boot 2.x to Spring Boot 3.x and replaced springdoc-openapi-ui dependency with springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.
After this migration, Swagger UI for the GET Apis which is accepting request parameters as List or List in the request object is not able to call and is considering as a string object.
With an API like this swagger is able to interpret as multi value parameter
  @GetMapping(value = "/test")
  public String test(@RequestParam List<String> values) {
    return "test";
  }


However, When I am passing an object like below, it is considering it as a string object and calling from swagger is being called like encoded string "{APIEndpoint}/test?values=%5B%22test%22%2C%22test1%22%5D"
  @GetMapping(value = "/test")
  public String test(TestDto testDto) {
    return "test";
  }


This was working fine before the migration. The solution so far I have found is to use @ParameterObject on the class level and after adding that it works fine.
We have 100's of GET API and adding this to each class will not be a possible solution. Is there any alternatives in OpenAPI through which we can solve this problem?

I have resolved something like this issue by adding these dependencies
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
implementation 'io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.15'

